# CreateArray fails with Unsupported feature : createArrayof in mule

Tags: java, mule, c3p0

dbCreateArray function fails while using Oracle DB with c3p0 connection pooling with error, java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature I am using below method

```
#[dbCreateArray(oracle_Configurtion, <USER_DEFINED_DATA_TYPE_NAME_AS_IN_ORACLE>, Object[])]
```

I am using mule EE 3.9, oracle 12.2.0 and c3p0 0.9.5.2

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"> 
<property name="driverClass" value = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" /> 
<property name="jdbcUrl" value = "${db.url}" /> 
<property name="user" value = "${db.username}" /> 
<property name="password" value = "${db.password}" /> 
<property name="initialPoolSize" value = "${pool.initialSize}" /> 
</bean>
```

I Have seen this blog he suggested switch to oracle ucp pool but is there any way to fix this issue when using c3p0 pool.

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/dbCreateArray-function-failing-with-DB-connection-pooling

Answer (score 0):

Oracle [does not support the JDBC4-standard `createArrayOf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/jdbcvers.htm#JJDBC28109).

Instead you must [call a proprietary `createARRAY` method](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraarr.htm#JJDBC28590).

If you were writing code directly, it's be no problem to `unwrap` the c3p0 `Connection` to the underlying Oracle `Connection` and call the proprietary method. However, it looks like you are working through a higher-level language that is presumably being translated to standard JDBC methods. Unless you can get under the covers of how that conversion is done, it probably won't be easy to get this higher-level language call to work.

It look's like Oracle's own UCP has built-in an Oracle-specific workaround, but `c3p0` does not include such a workaround, alas.